# Out-of-line variadic template function

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have a need to separate the declaration from the definition of a variadic template function:

```
struct A
{
    // In-line declaration of function
    template<typename...Args>
    A(Args&&...args);
};

// Out-of-line definition of function
template<typename...Args>
A<Args...>::A(Args&&...args)
{}

int main()
{
    A a("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

...here's the error I get (Clang 3.9 OS X 10):

```
main.cpp:8:2: error: expected unqualified-id
A<Args...>::A(Args&&...args)
 ^
```

Do I need to put 'typename' somewhere?  Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wrote:

```
template<typename...Args>
A<Args...>::A(Args&&...args)
{}
```

But your class isn't a *class-template*, so below is how you do it

```
template<typename...Args>
A::A(Args&&...args)
{}
```

---

---

Even if it was a *class-template*, the example below is how you deal with *class-template*'s templated constructor

```
template<typename... T>
struct A
{
    // In-line declaration of function
    template<typename...Args>
    A(Args&&...args);
};

// Out-of-line definition of function
template<typename... T>
template<typename... Args>
A<T...>::A(Args&&...args)
{}
```